# why is output of date function on node.js server wrong?

Tags: node.js, date, time, server, timezone

When date was 2018-03-21 19:40, i tried following code

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```

Output :

```
2018-03-21T16:40:53.755Z
```

Server is missing for 3 hours as you see. I fixed it by adding 3 hours but I think it's not a good way. How can i fix this problem with better way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the date is incorrect, if you look closely at the format it is being printed, it has a `Z` at the end, which [means](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt):

> A suffix which, when applied to a time, denotes a UTC offset of 00:00;
>   often spoken "Zulu" from the ICAO phonetic alphabet representation of
>   the letter "Z".

I guess you are in a place separated by 3 hours from UTC.

Node.js uses this format to print Date objects by default, but you can print your local time using [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Thanks, i have to get time of the date. Normally : `new Date().getTime();`is working but `new Date().toLocaleString().getTime()` is not working.

Comment: That does not work because `toLocaleString()` returns an string, that means you can't use any Date Object method (like `getTime()`).

But anyway there's no meaning doing that, since `toLocaleString()` doesn't change the internal date, it just gives you a representation of the date in your timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is most likely in another time zone.

Comment: Yes i know it, but i don't know how can i update to correct timezone

Comment: Why does it matter?